# Is it possible to port iOS app to windows store metro app

Tags: ios, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I'd like to port a simple iOS app to a windows metro app.

It's basically a web app wrapped around a `UINavigationController` and `UIWebView`. (link click pushes new `UIWebView` into `UINavigationController`)

Is this doable? How difficult would it be to do so?

Will I have to make significant changes on the server-side? Has anyone done something similar to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's really a web view wrapped in a navigation controller, the port in itself should be fairly easy, you should be able to wrap things in a similar way in a windows store app (ie a [WebView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview))

What may be the large part of the port unless you've been careful when creating the site is to see to that the app works well on *all resolutions*. iOS has a fairly small number of possible resolutions to support, while windows store apps support any resolution that Windows 8 supports (ie pretty much any current and/or future screen resolution) You'll more or less be required to use some kind of [responsive design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design).

Comment: Yes, it's a very simple app just like I described. Is there a sample  that does that?

Comment: @James Not quite sure, but [this sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452768.aspx) seems to cover most of what you need.